# ValueConverters in plataform projects

Tags: c#, mvvmcross

I want create a classic BooleanToVisibilityConverter for android, I follow this https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-04-ValueConverters, but in this sample all the converters are in Core project. I create my converter in Droid project and doesn't work.

My ValueConverter code:

```
public class BoolToVisibilityValueConverter : MvxValueConverter<bool, ViewStates>
    {
        protected override ViewStates Convert(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == true)
            {
                return ViewStates.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                return ViewStates.Gone;
            }
        }

        protected override bool ConvertBack(ViewStates value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == ViewStates.Gone)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else if (value == ViewStates.Invisible)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

And my layout where I use this converter.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        local:MvxBind="Text Message" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        local:MvxBind="Visibility ProgressBarVisibility,Converter=BoolToVisibility" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Edit:

Debug trace.

09-26 16:11:34.300 I/mono-stdout(18362): Parameter name: value
09-26 16:11:34.300 I/mono-stdout(18362):      at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Enum:ToObject (System.Type,object)
[0:] MvxBind:Error: 99.25 Problem seen during binding execution for to Visibility - problem ArgumentException: The value passed in must be an enum base or an underlying type for an enum, such as an Int32.
Parameter name: value
      at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Enum:ToObject (System.Type,object)
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.ExtensionMethods.MvxTypeExtensions.MakeSafeValue (System.Type propertyType, System.Object value) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding.MakeSafeValue (System.Object value) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding.SetValue (System.Object value) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.UpdateTargetFromSource (Boolean isAvailable, System.Object value) [0x00000] in :0 
09-26 16:11:34.300 I/mono-stdout(18362):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.ExtensionMethods.MvxTypeExtensions.MakeSafeValue (System.Type propertyType, System.Object value) [0x00000] in :0 
09-26 16:11:34.300 I/mono-stdout(18362):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding.MakeSafeValue (System.Object value) [0x00000] in :0 
09-26 16:11:34.300 I/mono-stdout(18362):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxPropertyInfoTargetBinding.SetValue (System.Object value) [0x00000] in :0 
09-26 16:11:34.300 I/mono-stdout(18362):   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.UpdateTargetFromSource (Boolean isAvailable, System.Object value) [0x00000] in :0 
El programa 'Mono' terminó con código 0 (0x0).

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What. Does the debug trace say? Converter not found? Or something else?

Comment: This is the debug Trace, sorry for not attach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to register that `ValueConverter` in your `Setup.cs` file, by overriding `ValueConverterAssemblies`.

```
protected override List<Assembly> ValueConverterAssemblies
{
    get
    {
        var toReturn = base.ValueConverterAssemblies;
        toReturn.Add(typeof(BoolToVisibilityValueConverter).Assembly);
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

You can read more about it here: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/Value-Converters#referencing-value-converters-in-touch-and-droid